# What is getParameterByName in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase says that in the [customize email action handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler#create_the_email_action_handler_page) that they will implement `getParameterByName`. What does that exactly mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

I'll assume you're referring to [this page of the Firebase Authentication documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler#create_the_email_action_handler_page), which contains the following code snippet:

```
  // TODO: Implement getParameterByName()

  // Get the action to complete.
  var mode = getParameterByName('mode');
  // Get the one-time code from the query parameter.
  var actionCode = getParameterByName('oobCode'};
  // (Optional) Get the API key from the query parameter.
  var apiKey = getParameterByName('apiKey'};
```

*Note that I only copied enough of the code to answer your question. Refer to the link for full code.*

The custom email handler is an HTML page that is invoked by Firebase when there is an action that you may want to respond to. The Firebase back-end informs your page of the action and its data, by passing these as URL parameters when invoking your page.

So say you have your custom handler in a page called `my_email_handler.html`, it may invoked your page as: `my_email_handler.html?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=123456&apiKey=AZdfshjsdfhj`

The/your page then parses these URL parameters and takes the appropriate (custom) action.

The comment is a TODO for you as the application developer, you will need to implement a `getParameterByName()` method that retrieves the value from a URL parameter with the given name. If you do a [search for getParameterByName](https://www.google.com/search?q=getParameterByName) you'll find quite some implementations of such a function.